# Rails 5 Geolocation with Clearance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, clearance

I'm currently using Clearance for authentication.  As part of the login process I want to ensure that I have a location for the user (stored in the session).

My question is how to do this in the context of clearance?  Ideally I only want to perform the lookup on login (to save network traffic / API calls).  If I can't locate a user then I'll deny login.

I was thinking of using a [guard](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance#extending-sign-in) but I don't seem to have access to `request.ip` or `session` which is a bit of a deal breaker.  I was also trying to avoid redirecting to a URL that only does the geolocation and then redirects again.

Anybody have ideas on a nice model on how to make this work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sign in guards are mostly intended for processes that will prevent or allow sign in. I don't think they are a good fit here. For this use case, I would suggest overriding `sign_in`, which is generally mixed in to `ApplicationController`

```
def sign_in(user, &block)
  super

  if signed_in?
    UserGeocoder.call(current_user)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Derek, I'll give this path a try as it definitely seems more appropriate than the Guard approach.